# Hide MasterView in SwiftUI on iPads programmatically

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to use this SplitView button on iPads programmatically:

[image: button]

I don't mean to deactivate the SplitView in general with `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` but to hide the MasterView in special situations while being inside the view which is what this automatically generated button does.

Is there a way in SwiftUI to do so?